# How to add Admob Interstitial before Segue?

Tags: swift, admob

I'v been trying to deal with this problem for a good while but cant figure out how to fix it.

Currently I'v added Admob to my project and the interstitial's are displaying but when I exit the interstitial it returns me to my previous VC (where the interstitial instance is made).

As you can see below im trying to add them to my Tabbar functions. But the segue never happens nor do the alerts show before the interstitial. I wanted to show the the ad then segue to the VC. And I want the user to see the alert and press "OK" before seeing the interstitial.

Any help would be awesome!

```
//TabBar Functions

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        if (item.tag == 1) {

            if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
                self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            }

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showStore", sender: nil)

        } else if (item.tag == 2) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Coming Soon!", message: "Loadout", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
                self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            }

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return

        } else if (item.tag == 3) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Coming Soon!", message: "God's Tower", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
                self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            }

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your `GADInterstitial`'s delegate and then segue once the ad has been dismissed.

```
// Add this where you're creating your GADInterstitial
interstitial.delegate = self

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
  // Segue to your view controller here
}
```

For a complete list of ad events refer to [GADInterstitialDelegate implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/ad-events).

Comment: Awesome Daniel! How can i use that function in my tabbar function though?

Comment: @brkr Use a global variable to store the value of the item.tag and then use a switch statement in the delegate method I've mentioned to present the correct view controller.